# Торговый агент — это коммивояжёр?

Tags: синонимы

Конечно мы понимаем, что можно назвать торгового агента коммивояжёром, но удачно ли это?

Answer (score 1):

Согласен вполне. В дословном переводе на русский язык коммивояжёр -комми -комерциал -торговый, если это слово заменит "коммерческий", вояжёр - путешественник, или путешественник с целью коммерческой выгоды, но не в смысле "челнок", а в смысле "представитель канадской компании".
Торговый агент в современном смысле слова -  работник коммерческой структуры, представляющий интересы компании, обычно при заключении сделок.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, неудачно, так как слово "коммивояжёр" чуждо русскому языку и по написанию, и по произношению. Вполне благозвучно, понятно и просто - "торговый агент"

Comment: Агент тоже нерусское слово, латинское. Опять же, по факту имеем два слова вместо одного родного и понятного.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, неудачно. Это не совсем одно и то же. 
Не буду грузить историческим деталями, ибо понятие об этой професии-должности сильно изменились с момента появления её на российской почве в конце XIX века.

Достаточно того, что коммивояжер - **разъездной** торговый агент. Неразъездного обычно называют торговым представителем. Так что торговый агент - шире.

Comment: А есть ли синоним словосочетания "торговый агент"?

Comment: не знаю такого. А зачем? Это понятие само по себе является термином, вошедшим в специальные словари ([тут][1]). Да и английскому оригиналу (selling agent) вполне себе соответствует.

  1: http://www.finam.ru/dictionary/wordf02E050002D/default.asp?n=1